# Execute multiple commands on remote server using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to execute cd and scp commands on a remote server which have to be logged in with a different sudo user. Below code snippet asks for the password(echos on screen) for my user but hangs there. It doesn't execute cd

```
#!/bin/bash
server=myserver.com
ssh $server 'sudo -S -u <user> -i; cd dir1/dir2/; scp file1 user@local-sever'
```

Comment: i tested with: ssh  user@IP  'cd /etc && cat passwd'

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have a semi colon before cd and so sudo has no command to execute. Remove the ; and it should work:

```
ssh $server 'sudo -S -u <user> -i scp dir1/dir2/file1 user@local-sever'
```

Comment: Note that the sudo ends with the `cd` and the default user might not have permissions for the `scp`.

Comment: Good point @Paul Hodges, I've amended the solution.

Comment: @RamanSailopal That seems to work but scp command isn't working. It is not even asking for password.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to address this, but most boil down to wrapping up the commands into a set of instructions. Raman's solution is good since it handles the issue by using full paths, but sometimes that isn't an option. Here's another take -

Assuming your command list can afford the quotes, I like here-strings.

```
ssh -t sa-nextgen-jenkins.eng.rr.com <<< "
  echo 'set -x; cd /tmp; whoami; touch foo; ls -l foo; rm -f foo;'|sudo -iSu user
"
```

If you need the quotes, try a here-doc.

```
ssh -t sa-nextgen-jenkins.eng.rr.com <<END
  echo 'set -x; echo "$RANDOM"; cd /tmp; whoami; touch foo; ls -l foo; rm -f foo;'|sudo -iSu $user
END
```

You can also write a small script that has arbitrarily complex commands and scp it over, then use a remote ssh call to execute it as the relevant user.